# java: pass an object and return same object's type

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, abstract-class

I have an abstract class A

```
public astract class A{
   public abstract A f(A a) throws IllegalArgumentException;
};
```

but I want object a passed to f to have the same type of the object itself and return an object of same type, otherwise throw an IllegalArgumentException. How can I implement that one time for all subclasses? There is a way to do that at the class A level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not provide a way to state this requirement declaratively. However, you can make a run-time check at the level of your abstract class by following the [*Template Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern:

```
public abstract class A {
    public final A f(A a) {
        if (a.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        A res = fImpl(a);
        if (res.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return res;
    }
    protected abstract A fImpl(A a); // Implementing classes put functionality here
}
```

The above code changes `f(A)` from abstract method to *template method* by providing shared functionality for all subclasses of `A`. In this case the shared functionality is argument checking, and also the return type checking.

This is the method that the clients of your class are going to use. The implementors of the abstract class, on the other hand, will be implementing `fImpl` method, which can assume that its argument `A` is a subclass that matches their own class.

Comment: Surely you can do it with Generics? `<T extends A> T f(T a)`?

Comment: @EJP My understanding is that OP wants the class extending `A` to be the same class as the one implementing `f`. In other words, when you write `B`, its `f` should look as follows: `class B { public B f(B a) {} }`

Comment: @dasblickenlight Yes, that is what I want! Why EJP's answer does not the job?

Comment: the problem in EJP's answer as I understand is that generics evaporate at RT, so you don't have a way to check the real type of the object @ RT using generics

Comment: @bluePhlavio Because it lets `f` of `class B` to take and return `class C` objects, as long as both `B` and `C` derive from `A`. In other words, it does not enforce your "the same type of the object itself" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class A
{
    public A f(A a) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (!this.getClass().equals(a.getClass()))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what is I want to keep f abstract?